# Ordering tasks by dependency in Java

Tags: java, arrays, dependencies

I was given a question where there is a task amount determined by the user.
There is a method which adds a dependency, in example I have 6 tasks which are represented by index 0-5. If I add a dependency means second paramater needs to be completed before the first one:

```
    Tasks t = new Tasks(6);
t.dependsOn(3, 2);
t.dependsOn(0, 3);
t.dependsOn(2, 5);
t.dependsOn(4, 5);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t.order()));
```

**output:** [1, 5, 2, 3, 0, 4]

We are instructed to work with 2d arrays to store dependencies and then make a new int array with the correct order and return it.
I have managed to store the dependencies in 2d array represented by indexes of rows and columns.
First two in my output array are correct (1,5), because my code detects non-dependent tasks but the else I cant manage to insert.

```
package tasks;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tasks {

private int num;
private int dep[][];

public Tasks(int num) {
    this.num = num;
    dep = new int[num][num];

}

public boolean dependsOn(int task1, int task2) {
    if (task1 > num - 1 || task2 > num - 1 || task1 < 0 || task2 < 0 || task1 == task2) {
        return false;
    } else
        dep[task1][task2] = 1;
    return true;

}

public int[] order() {
    int[] tasks = new int[num];
    int k = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    
    int[] visited = new int[num];

    
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            if (dep[i][j] == 1) {
                
                flag++;
                System.out.println(i + " " + j);
                print();
                dep[i][j]--;
                
                visited[j]++;
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(visited));
                
            }

        }
        if (flag == 0) {

            tasks[k] = i;
            k++;

        }


        flag = 0;

    }

    print();
    return tasks;
}

public void print() {

    for (int row = 0; row < dep.length; row++)// Cycles through rows
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < dep[row].length; col++)// Cycles through columns
        {
            System.out.printf("%5d", dep[row][col]); // change the %5d to however much space you want
        }
        System.out.println(); // Makes a new row
    }

    System.out.println();
}
}
```

Comment: are you having an exception on the else or what is it exactly that you are having a problem with?

Comment: im inserting only non dependant values. in that case 1,5

Comment: I wonder what else is in your array? after 1,5.  Is it empty?

your else is missing brackets else{
      dep[task1][task2] = 1;
return true;
}  Is that intentional?